# JavaScript: "keydown" EventListener not working unless I click on the actual button first?

Tags: javascript

I am making an in-browser vanilla JavaScript calculator and am trying to give it keyboard functionality. The problem I am having is getting the EventListener to work with the "keydown" action. 
Here is my JS code below:

```
const buttonchoices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button[data-key]"));
buttonchoices.forEach(key => key.addEventListener("keydown", e =>{
    const key = document.querySelector(`button[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    console.log(e)
}));
```

and the supporting HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calculator" class="allbtns">
        <input type="text" name="display" id="display" style="grid-area: display" disabled>
        <!--Numbers-->
        <button id="9" data-key="57" value="9" class="number" style="grid-area:nine">9</button>
        <button id="decimal" data-key="190" class ="number" style="grid-area:decimal" value=".">.</button>
        <!--Operations-->
        <button id="+" data-key="187" value="+" class="number operations" style="grid-area:add">+</button>
        <button id="operate" data-key="13" value="="  class="number operate" style="grid-area:operate">=</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
</html>
```

I tried to workaround this problem by adding an eventlistener for the whole document (ie window.addEventListener("keydown",etc..)) and that got the console.log to print something, but I cannot call any function with it. 
So as of now, when I press any of the keys nothing happens.

Comment: The `keydown` event is fired on whatever element has the focus (and then bubbles up the DOM if configured to). That's why you have to click it (or tab to it) in order for it to "hear" the event. I'm not sure why you "cannot call any function" when using an event listener on `window`. Perhaps add the event listener to `document.documentElement` or `document.body`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey this should definitely be an answer, as it's the best way to do this.

Comment: @syedmh I'm waiting for clarification from the OP as to why they cannot call functions from the event listener attached to `window`, because it will mean less back and forth on any answer. I'm also sure there's a duplicate out there...

Comment: @HereticMonkey @syedmh I believe I was targeting the wrong input into my function (e vs key), but it works now with using the event listener on `window`. So would I have to deselect/unfocus on another element to "listen" to a more specific one? Would it be better practice to listen to the whole window instead of a const defined array of buttons?

Comment: If you listen to `keydown` on `window`, you only need to add event listeners for the `click` event on the `button` elements. I'll explain more in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed things a bit in the code to make it easier to understand:

- I moved all of the key-handling code to a `handleKey` function that takes the value of the key pressed (or the value of the button clicked). This makes it easier than looking up key codes, and [the `KeyboardEvent` has a `key` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) that exposes that information to us.
- I chose to add the `keydown` listener to the `documentElement` (`html` element) because I'm old and that's what I'm used to.  Basically in that listener, all you do is handle the key pressed and prevent the default.

  - Preventing the default stops the key from doing what it normally does (typing out the number, submitting the form, whatever), so use it with care. You may want to filter the keys to only those you actually use in the `handleKey` function (maybe make an array of `handledKeys` and check if `e.key` is in there and only call `e.preventDefault()` if so).
- Then I used basically the same code as you previously used to add a `keydown` event listener to the buttons to add a `click` event listener to the buttons, which just defers to the `handleKey` function. I used `e.preventDefault()` again. If you add `type="button"` to all of the buttons, you could remove that.

```js
function handleKey(key) {
  const display = document.getElementById('display');
  switch (key) {
    case '9': display.value += '9'; break;
    case '.': display.value += display.value.includes('.') ? '' : '.'; break;
    case '+': console.log('add'); break;
    case 'Enter': console.log('equals'); break;
  }
}

document.documentElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  handleKey(e.key);
  e.preventDefault();
});

document.querySelectorAll('button[data-key]').forEach(button => 
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    handleKey(e.target.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  })
);
```

```html
<div id="calculator" class="allbtns">
  <input type="text" name="display" id="display" style="grid-area: display" disabled>
  <!--Numbers-->
  <button id="9" data-key="57" value="9" class="number" style="grid-area:nine">9</button>
  <button id="decimal" data-key="190" class="number" style="grid-area:decimal" value=".">.</button>
  <!--Operations-->
  <button id="+" data-key="187" value="+" class="number operations" style="grid-area:add">+</button>
  <button id="operate" data-key="13" value="Enter" class="number operate" style="grid-area:operate">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I think I get the underlying logic behind this now. Much appreciated!